# Laravel 5.5 works "/" route only

Tags: php, laravel

I'm here with an unusual issue from me because i've never had this problem before so i need some help to solve it.

Server information:
-Ubuntu 16.04
-PHP v7.2
-Laravel 5.5.39

The project that i'm trying to install is already installed on my others computers and working fine.

What i tried after the project clone is:
-Composer install
-.env setup
-Enabling rewrite apache mod
-Altering some .htaccess directions (I think it's not the issue)

After it i got 404 error (The requested URL /public/register was not found on this server)

Thanks!

Comment: in your `.htaccess` file is there a reference to `/public/registe`r?  or a link in your code which points to that location and is not correct?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. The url showed above is just an example. That route i got on my routes file. The error happens with any route and only works with "/" route

Comment: So your example is not the problem? maybe you should detail more in your question about the actual problem and some of your htaccess.

Comment: If you have properly defined route /register and it is working than why are you trying to access it with /public/register? If not and /register route is also not working, you most probably have configuration problem in your webserver. Please note that your webserver should point to /public/index.php as document root for laravel

Comment: Hello! I just copied and pasted that example. I think that the problem is with apache configuration or something like this not with .htaccess file.
What do you mean with point my webserver to that route ? Thanks!